# How can I call multiple validation functions in my Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to validate my form prior to calling the function that inserts records into the database.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSignup").click(function () {
            ///////////CAN I PUT SOMETHING HERE TO HANDLE VALIDATION?
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "/Newsletter/Signup",
                data: $('#signupForm').serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        $('#signupMessage').show(0);
                    }
                    else {
                        showValidationErrors(response.Data);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Is it possible for me to insert something here that validates my form and then, if it validates, goes on to call the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can certainly put any function before the ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSignup").click(function () {
        //create a function which will do the form validation and then call it here.
        if(form_valid()) // This will do the form validation and then only send the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/Newsletter/Signup",
            data: $('#signupForm').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $('#signupMessage').show(0);
                }
                else {
                    showValidationErrors(response.Data);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for writing.  I appreciate your help very much.